# anchor disappears so onClick event doesn't happen as it is faded out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor (`<a>`) that appears only when an `<input />` is focused. The moment the `<input />` is blurred, the anchor's container fades out.

I'm trying to click on the anchor to trigger the `onClick()` event for it, but the moment I click, the focus changes, from the input, and the anchor's container disappears. I believe this is why when I click the anchor nothing happens.

How can I check on the blur event of the `<input />` if the anchor was just clicked and that is what caused the focus to change from the `<input />` and cause the blur event?

Then, if the blur event occurred because I clicked on the anchor, I can trigger the `onClick()` and if not, I can fade out the anchor's container.

How can I do this javascript / jQuery ?

**Update:**

I am currently trying to do the following in javascript:

On blur of input, if `.ss-result a` was not clicked then fade out, else alert(".ss-result a clicked!");

Here is the code that I am trying to accomplish this with, but it breaks my fading in of the anchor on focus of `<input />`. I'm not getting any console errors.

```
var inputObj = $('input');
var boxObj = $('.container');
inputObj.blur(function() {
    if($('.ss-result a').is(':focus')){
        alert(".ss-result a clicked!");)
    }
    else{
        boxObj.fadeOut(100);
    }
});
```

Comment: Need to post your code or we can't see what's going wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan Inside the click or the blur?

Comment: @Coop Here is a JS Fiddle, but it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7vSV/

Comment: Works fine... Problem must be something else

Comment: @Coop I updated with code and what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Jonathan I updated my question with code and what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: If the fiddle works but the code with `if($('.ss-result a').is(':focus'))` doesn't, I'd start looking there.

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you. I thought that was the problem. But I don't know how else to write if .ss-result a was clicked and took the focus from the input.

Comment: Why check at all? Try to fade it out regardless and do a .show() in the onclick

Comment: How is this different from your last question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196361/on-blur-of-input-if-click-on-a-caused-blur-then-do-something

Answer (score -1):

#### CSS pseudoclass ":focus-within"

Instead of using JQuery, I reccomend using the ":focus-within" pseudoclass in a parent element so that the checkbox keeps visible until the user interacts with an external element.

```html
<style>
   .checkbox {
      display: none; /* You can replace this with "visibility: hidden" */
   }
   .container:focus-within > .checkbox {
      display: block; /* And this with "visibility: visible" */
   }
</style>

<div class="container">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
</div>
```

##### Adding a transition

You can also add a transition to make it fade out. You should set the opacity to 0 and the visibility to hidden as a default state and change it every time the user focuses the container:

```css
.checkbox, .checkboxLabel {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

div:focus-within>* {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text"><br>
  <label for="mycheck" class="checkboxLabel">Checkbox:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="mycheck">
</div>
```