# on blur of <input />, if click on <a> caused blur, then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to do the following in javascript / jQuery:

On blur of input, if `.ss-result a` was not clicked then fade out, else alert(".ss-result a clicked!");

Here is the code that I am trying to accomplish this with, but it breaks my fading in of the anchor on focus of `<input />`. I'm not getting any console errors.

```
var inputObj = $('input');
var boxObj = $('.container');
inputObj.blur(function() {
    if($('.ss-result a').is(':focus')){
        alert(".ss-result a clicked!");)
    }
    else{
        boxObj.fadeOut(100);
    }
});
```

Comment: How is this different from your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195426/anchor-disappears-so-onclick-event-doesnt-happen-as-it-is-faded-out?

Comment: @j08691 I felt that the update I made to the earlier question was a different request / question so I made it its own question.